# Pegar chaves de um array

Tags: php, mysql

estou ultilizando `PDO` para consulta mysql,e eu gostaria de pegar as chaves de um array, ja tentei diversos métodos e não obteve sucesso, ex:`$arr_cars['id']` ocorreu um erro

```
class Cars extends DB{
    static function getCars(){

    $select = self::getConn()->prepare('SELECT id,image,carro FROM `cars`');
    $d = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $d;

    }
}
    //classe 

 $data = Cars::getCars();
 $arr_cars = array();

foreach($data as $key){ 
   $arr_cars[] = $key;
}

var_dump($cars);

/*irá imprimir:

array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'image' => string '1.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'bmw' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'image' => string '2.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'mercedes' (length=17)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'image' => string '3.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'bentley' (length=9)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'image' => string '3.jpg' (length=5)
      'carro' => string 'volvo' (length=12)
```

Comment: O quevocê está tentando fazer? Por que você está tentando criar um array idêntico a partir de outro?

Comment: @Rodrigo Rigotti eu fiz um select no banco de dados  que tem 4 registros e imprimir o resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função key():

```
<?php
$array = array(
"one" => 1,
"two" => 2,
"three" => 3,
"four" => 4
);

while($element = current($array)) {
echo key($array)."\n";
next($array);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hat o problema é que nesse banco de dados o usuário faz insert quase todos os dias, imagina o trabalho de editar o script quando atualizar as chaves, tem outro método?

Comment: @David esse é o exemplo para pegar a chave, você ira usá-la, depois do `select` e do `fetch_all`, são eles quem irão gerar as chaves....

Comment: era isso que estava procurando, funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Poderia validar  alguma das respostas, se corretas. Clicando no sinal verde abaixo das setas de avaliação.

Answer (score 7):

Se o que pretendes é a chave da matriz, deves fazer uso da seguinte sintaxe do [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
```

Assim, a cada iteração, a chave do elemento é atribuída à primeira variável, e os dados do elemento são atribuídos à segunda variável.

No teu caso ficaria:

```
$arr_cars = array();

foreach ($data as $chave => $dados) {

   $arr_cars[] = $chave;
}
```

---

Ainda mais eficiente, é a função [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php) que te retoma todas as chaves duma matriz:

```
$arr_cars = array_keys($data);
```